# Passing SQL function in quoted string inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-function

I am trying to write a dynamic SQL query - trying to pass column names in parameter. Problem I am facing is that when I try to pass SQL function `Convert` in string parameter, SQL Server raises syntax error. Without function, Query is executed perfectly fine. Error is:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

There is no **dot '.'** I can see in my query. But yes, the numeric value being passed as an argument to `Convert` is float value. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks alot.

```
declare

@orderBy nvarchar(200),
@sortOrder nvarchar(40), 
@fieldlist nvarchar(max),
@STMT nvarchar(max)

set @orderBy = 'Symbol'
set @sortOrder = 'Asc'
SET @fieldlist = 'Symbol, [Net Qty], [Total BUY], [Avg. BUY RATE], [Trans. Amount], [MTM Price], [MTM Amount], [Total SELL], [Avg. SELL RATE], [PENDING BUY], [PENDING SELL],  Convert(numeric(10,2),[SETTLED P/L]) as [SETTLED P/L],
 Convert(numeric(10,2),[UNSETTLED P/L]) as [UNSETTLED P/L] '


SET @STMT =  'SELECT  ' + @fieldlist + 
                  'FROM    (
                            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @orderBy + ' '+@sortOrder+' '+') AS row, *
                            FROM    ' + '[Cats(Main)].[dbo].SESSION_HOLDING' + '
                            WHERE   ' + 'AccountNo = '''+'00'+'''' + '
                          ) AS tbl
WHERE
                          row > ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @lbound) + ' AND
                          row < ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @ubound)'


EXEC (@STMT)
```

Comment: First comment would be that you are declaring fieldlist but you are using fieldset. Is that correct? Are you declaring fieldset somewhere else?

Comment: @jyparask Oh sorry, its typo mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: I would suggest replace EXEC with PRINT and get the output and run it and see how it goes.

Comment: I tried running that with PRINT and there is no problem there. I do get an SQL query that seems valid. Running that though, might provide more details.

Comment: You are right. I printed the query and executed it. It got me results. Don't know what's the problem :S

Comment: Is this in an SP or Function? You cannot run dynamic queries in a Function.

Comment: @jyparask It is an SP.

Comment: Have you tried only with one convert? Then with only the other? This may narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36077/discussion-between-jyparask-and-anum90)

Comment: After changing `EXEC` to `PRINT`, copy the output and run it as a separate query. This should give the same error. It might even tell you where the error is. If not, incrementally remove data from the query to narrow down the error. This should tell you where the problem is. If you don't know how to fix it, you can [edit] your question to ask about that. My guess is that the problem is with `[Cats(Main)].[dbo].SESSION_HOLDING`, as that's the only `.`'s I see not in `[]`, though, not knowing anything about your database, I can't tell for sure.